# Xamarin sqlite mapping models to database table

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite.net

I have deployed a database file for a xamarin project using the following guide. http://arteksoftware.com/deploying-a-database-file-with-a-xamarin-forms-app/

I created a model class as such:

```
[Table ("Person")]
public class Person  
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotNull, Column("Actor_Id")]
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to do an insert in the repository

```
dbConn.Insert(newPerson);
```

I'm getting SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: table Person has no column named ActorId.

If the column name in the database is Actor_Id shouldn't the [Column] attribute in the model map it to the table.

Comment: Which library are you using: SQLite.Net-PCL Or sqlite-net ?

Comment: I'm using SQLite.Net-PCL

Comment: I know I can change the variable name to Actor_Id to match the table column but I wanted to know if it's possible to map it with a different name through the Column Attribute.

Comment: Yes, you can column attribute with the different name. Please delete old database and application and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your phone/emulator is previously deployed with app that with older database schema.

In this case, you will need to:

- Remove the existing app in your phone/emulator. Then the next run should be OK due to it is created using new database schema. OR
- Perform database upgrade script to change the schema of the current old database. Only do this if your app is already publish to store.

Comment: I reinstalled the app but I'm still getting the same error. I added the database file first then created the model. The database comes with existing data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be that I was using the SQLite library in the model. Changing it to use SQLite.Net.Attributes allowed the correct mapping.

```
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
```